# Generating Tiles with QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there any in the year 2019 working plugin? I try QTiles but this make errors (https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles/issues/100). So I need an alternative that is working with QGIS 3.6
How I can produce tiles from maps I produce with QGIS? On Windows, if possible without any scripting.

Comment: Qtiles is not officially supported by QGIS 3.x. See https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles/issues/94 I don't understand why Qtiles3 fork points on original  qtiles issue tracker.

Answer (score 4):

Open the QGIS 3x change log (in my case 3.8).

https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog38/#feature-generate-raster-xyz-tiles
You should have the Qtiles option in the Processing toolbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin it's a native feature of QGIS save as geopackage or Mbtiles (both are SQLITE) if you want folder of tiles just use python mbutil or others to extract. There is also GDAL2TILES_parallel.py give it a TIf  makes folder of tiles. You can still download QGIS 2.18x And use the plugins that have not migrated to 3x. QGIS-LTR is now at 3x.

Comment: I don't see this. What I think is wanted is a way to construct tiles that replicate a QGIS project, showing all the layers rendered into PNG (or JPG) at each zoom level, as you would see it in QGIS. None of the Project Save As or Export menu options will do it. The QTiles plugin works for me on an example I just tried - Qgis 3.6 with QTiles3 1.6.0

Comment: You can make group layer and export or save as individual. Turn on experimental plugins and also try QMETATILES.

Comment: Correct
The problem is that Qmetatiles did not work in 3.6 and in 2.x my maps don't work (many corrections are necassary) :-(

Comment: Simple export tif, then run python gdal2tiles_parallel.py

Comment: https://gitlab.com/GitLabRGI/erdc/geopackage-python

Comment: Add tile layer or tilegrid plugin to see tile boundaries

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.
If I export a image I lost all the QGIS possibilities like "showing parts in special scales only" (?) QTiles3 works perfect for converting raster images.